# Qtip2 show tooltip only once

Tags: jquery, qtip2, jquery-cookie

I can't find a proper answer to this question. **How can I set my tooltip to appear only once per visitor?**
The only answer I found on some forum was to add this

```
 $('.selector').qtip({
   content: 'blah',
   api: {
      onHide: function(event, api) {
         api.destroy();
      }
   }
});
```

but I know it's not recommended and it doesn't works anyway.

This is how my code looks like:

```
$('#win').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Some text',
        title: {
         text: 'Some other text',
         button: 'Close' // Close button
      }
        },
    show: {
            event: false,
            when: true,
            ready: true
        },
     position: {
        my: 'top right',  
        at: 'bottom left',
        target: $('#win')
     },
        hide: false 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable and disable your tooltip at any time with method `disable(true/false)`.

If you want to show it only once:

```
$('#win').on('mouseleave', function(){
    var $item = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
         $item.qtip('api').disable(true);
    },0);
});
```

Later you can enable tooltip: `$('#win').qtip('api').disable(false);`

Solution with jquery-cookie.js looks like this:

```
var $win = $('#win').qtip();

if($.cookie('win')) $win.qtip('api').disable(true);

$win.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $.cookie('win', 'true');

    var $item = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
       $item.qtip('api').disable(true);
    }, 0);
});
```